# Insert Text into Tkinter.Text, throws error

Tags: text, python-2.7, insert, tkinter

Im very new to Python and trying to set text to a Text field.
But its not going so well. i've followed many tutorials and written the exact same code. but it still not works.
what am i doing wrong ?

```
def initGUI():
    global root,TextField
    root = Tkinter.Tk();        
    TextField = Tkinter.Text(root, width = 50, height= 10);
    TextField.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT,pady=(0,5), expand=Tkinter.YES, fill=Tkinter.BOTH);
    Tkinter.mainloop();

def main():
    initGUI()
    global TextField
    TextField.insert(INSERT,"Hello ?") # Tried Tkinter.INSERT / "1.0"


import Tkinter
main()
```

Im running Python 2.7.5

Comment: Post the error you're getting and I'm sure a lot more people are willing to look into your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself.

The mainloop was accidently indented to initGui.
That ment it was not able to change the text at all.